# Pattern matching multiple cases with same action

Tags: .net-core, polymorphism, pattern-matching

Hello i have an `abstract` class with `2` derived classes.The nature of the hierarchy puts me in the undesired position where both the `derived` members share a common  `property` but the superclass does not have it.
So while i have 2 derived classes that have a common property i need to pattern match in a `switch` statement both these cases **AND** apply the same **Action** on them:

```
public abstract class Base
{

}
public D1:Base{
   public long Value{get;set;}
   public void SetValue(long val){
        this.Value=val;
   }
}
public D2:Base
{
   public long Value{get;set;}
   public void SetValue(long val)
   { 
      this.Value=val;
   }
}

public void PaternMatch(Base base)
{
    long val=5;
    switch(base)
    {
     case D1 d1:
     case D2 d2:
     //how can i say something like apply `SetValue regardless if its d1 or d2?
     d1.SetValue(val)?
     break;

}
```

**Update** is there any construct that lets me get the type when having multiple cases with the same action?

```
case string:
case int:
case double:
 Console.WriteLine("the option that matched was:"+[ option name of or value  ]`);
```

In the above  case can i know that `string` matched ,or int ? or at least get an index of which one matched ? `0-string`,`1-int`,`2 -double`

Comment: Hi, look at docs for "when" keyword:

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#when

Comment: I do not see how can i make use of it . In my case there is no extra condition on top of the maching case.I have 2 cases and i want the same action to be applied , (albeit differently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var d1 = new D1();
        PatternMatch(d1);

        Debug.Assert(d1.Value.Equals(5));
        Console.WriteLine(d1.Value);

        var d2 = new D2();
        PatternMatch(d2);
        Debug.Assert(d2.Value.Equals(5));
        Console.WriteLine(d2.Value);

        var d3 = new D3();
        PatternMatch(d3);
        Debug.Assert(d3.Value.Equals(105));
        Console.WriteLine(d3.Value);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void PatternMatch(BaseD baseD)
    {
        long val = 5;
        switch (baseD)
        {
            // first case for self class, then check is d1 or d2... 
            case BaseD @base when @base is D1 || @base is D2:
                // then, cause base does not implement SetValue method, we need to cast to D1 or to D2 and invoke SetValue(val);
                switch (@base)
                {
                    case D1 d1:
                        d1.SetValue(val);
                        break;
                    case D2 d2:
                        d2.SetValue(val);
                        break;
                }

                break;
            case D3 d3:
                d3.SetValue(val);
                break;

        }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseD
{

}

public class D1 : BaseD
{
    public long Value { get; private set; }

    public void SetValue(long val)
    {
        this.Value = val;
    }
}

public class D2 : BaseD
{
    public long Value { get; private set; }

    public void SetValue(long val)
    {
        this.Value = val;
    }
}

public class D3 : BaseD
{
    public long Value { get; private set; }

    public void SetValue(long val)
    {
        this.Value = val + 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i somehow not do the inner switch ? Can i somehow infer if `@base is D1 d`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian, i tried without inner switch case like that:
```when @base is D1 d1 || @base is D2 d2:
d1?.SetValue(val);
d2?.SetValue(val);```
but compiler says that d1 and d2 is not instanciated...
I don't know why :) may be it's a bug.)